# Multiple users control

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to create a script page using PHP or Javascript to:
multiple control for all users.
exemple:
- a page with an audio sound Player,
for exemple 3 users conntected to this script page
when some one of thos users click on Start playing, it will play for all users, and when an other click on Stop it will stop playing for all user.
= all users have the same controle permission.
is some one have an idea to create this with a flexible languague please, it's very important.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour before you continue.

Answer (score 1):

I take you already have loaded the video/audio and the page is hosted and ready and you are only looking into controlling it by multiple users.

One way is to listen to the events or change in status of the play/pause/stop properties of the player. If you are familiar with Firebase (realtime database), you want to create a document with play, pause and stop <==> Player propeties. When the user clicks on any one of the button on the player save it to Firebase against its property.

For every change to the document Firebase will automatically propagate it to all connected users. And on the page you can call the play(),pause(),stop() functions of the player based on the switch status. Hope this helps to get you started. Obviously there will be other ways. This is just one of it.

[Functions for html player](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

[Firebase for web with Javascript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start)

Comment: i thing that it will be not fast if i send command to database to change current mode on all users screen, do you think so ?

Comment: I cannot really comment on availability or speed..it becomes context specific.. But surely it is something that is already taken care of by the service..You should check out projects or their youtube channel if you are worried about how to use Firebase or performance. It is actually very simple. (My opinion)